# Running VS2017 application in Windows 7

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, windows-7

I developed the VC++ application using Visual studio 2017 in Windows 10 OS. My target system is Windows XP or Windows 7 32 bit. What are all the changes I should do to make the application work properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: XP ? Why? It is not supported anymore. It is highly insecure.

Comment: As noted, you should really look closely at any "requirement" to support Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

You can get VS 2017 code to work on Windows XP Service Pack 3 by using the `v141_xp` platform toolset which uses a Windows 7.1A SDK and setting `_WINNT_WIN32=0x0502`.

> You need to install the optional component that adds Windows XP support via the Visual Studio Installer.

You also need to avoid using any APIs that are unsupported on Windows XP, but that's a case-by-case problem you'll likely have to solve by trying to run the code and debugging launch failures.

See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1/) for some additional notes related to DirectX headers.